# Webforms - '[+] Add more fields' (up to 5) button to file upload form control

Tags: webforms

I managed to add fields to submit attachments in a webform.
Now all I need is to restyle them to only allow one upload per charge plus a 'add more button'. I need to restyle the 1 into 2.

How can this easily achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this [Webform Add](http://drupal.org/project/webform_addmore) module ?

> Webform Add More enables selected fieldsets to be initially hidden and
>   progressively shown with an Add more button, mimicking CCK multiple
>   fields.

Comment: I was not able to find that checkbox to activate the module. This would be what I am looking for.

Comment: Also is working inside fieldsets which is not possible in my situation

Comment: I have hundreds of forms and I need a programmatic way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which relies on javascript, here below is the skeleton:

```
    $("#edit-submitted-file-ajax-wrapper").after('<a id="addmore" href=#>[+] Add more</a>');
          //this vars are available inside bind function due to js scope
          var c = 1;//counter
          var wrapper_to_clone;
          $('#addmore').bind('click', function(e) {
            //clone filed and change attributes
            wrapper_to_clone = $("#edit-submitted-file-ajax-wrapper");
            field_to_clone = $("#edit-submitted-file-ajax-wrapper input");
            wrapper_to_clone.clone().attr('id', 'edit-submitted-file' + c + '-ajax-wrapper').insertAfter(wrapper_to_clone);
            //here you need to rename the attributes of children
            ...    
            ++c;

            if (c == 5) {
              return false;
            }
     });
```